# New button on Related list to be active based on condition

Tags: apex, visualforce, validation

I have a Sturdy(Custom Object) related list under Account object, i do want to make the New button of the Sturdy related list to be displayed only if the Account status is Active?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to make two record types (active & inactive), and then assign a different page layout for each record type. Only add the button to the related list on the active page layout.

Use workflow rules to assign the record type based on status.

Comment: No i dont want that way, since we already have 5 different record types. Client wont accept it.

Comment: Then you can use a Javascript button to action based on the Account status, but it will always be present on the page.